# How to use condition inside LAST_VALUE() function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where table column A has two values X1 and 1. It is randomly ordered. I want to get the last numeric value for the entire column. My query is as below:

```sql
LAST_VALUE(MAN.CODE) OVER (ORDER BY LINE.DATE ASC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) .
```

The query returns the last value (in this case 'X1') , however I need to return last numeric value (1) for the entire column.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? It tells you where to put the scalar expression. What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Put it in your question, use the [edit] feature, not the comments.

Comment: @Larnu edited the description

Comment: What if there is no numeric value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *assume* this'll work, but with no sample data, difficult to say:

```sql
LAST_VALUE(MAN.CODE) OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,MAN.CODE) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, LINE.DATE ASC
                           RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

This *assumes* your `varchar` column contains only strings formatted as an `int`; you might need to use a different data type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take into account that there might not be a numeric value.  If so, you would need additional logic:

```
(case when try_convert(numeric,
                       first_value(man.code) over (order by case when try_convert(numeric, man.code) is not null then 1 else 2 end,
                                                   line.date desc
                                                  )
      then first_value(man.code) over (order by case when try_convert(numeric, man.code) is not null then 1 else 2 end,
                                                line.date desc
                                      )
 end) as last_numeric
```

I tend to prefer `first_value()` with a descending sort because it doesn't require a window frame clause.